# Parsing an xml file and creating another from the parsed object

Tags: python, lxml

I am trying to parse an xml file(containing bad characters) using lxml module in `recover = True` mode.
Below is the code snippet

```
from lxml import etree
f=open('test.xml')
data=f.read()
f.close()
parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)
x = etree.fromstring(data, parser=parser)
```

Now I want to create another xml file (test1.xml) from the above object (`x`)
Could anyone please help in this matter.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are searching for

```
from lxml import etree

# opening the source file
with open('test.xml','r') as f:
    # reading the number
    data=f.read()
   
parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)
# fromstring() parses XML from a string directly into an Element
x = etree.fromstring(data, parser=parser)

# taking the content retrieved
y = etree.tostring(x, pretty_print=True).decode("utf-8")

# writing the content on the output file
with open('test1.xml','w') as f:
    f.write(y)
```